# How to maintain a reference to a std::priority_queue's container?

Tags: c++, vector, queue, containers

I'm creating a `std::priority_queue` using `std::vector` as container.

It seems like the priority queue creates a copy of the container passed to it in its constructor, since changes made to the container after constructing the queue aren't reflected in the queue's container.

For example, if I call `clear()` on my container, the priority queue remains full.

Is there a way to maintain a reference to the priority queue's internal container after construction?

Comment: Note that you can derive from `priority_queue` and your derived class can access the container (which I believe is aptly called `c`).

Comment: example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45309406/2015579

Comment: Thanks Richard, that's the method I'm now using and it's working great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::priority_queue` is one of the few standard containers designed to be derived from.

It has a protected member `c` which is the container.

You can derived from the queue and use `c` in your derived class.

If you mutate the container, remember that it's actually a `heap` and needs to have the appropriate heap functions applied to it before you leave your method.

```
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>

struct my_special_queue : std::priority_queue<int>
{
    using underlying_queue = std::priority_queue<int>;

    // re-use all constructors
    using underlying_queue::underlying_queue;

    // add a clear method

    void clear()
    {
        underlying_queue::c.clear();
    }

    void remove_all_odd_numbers()
    {
        c.erase(std::remove_if(c.begin(), c.end(), 
                                [](auto&&x) { return (x % 2) == 1; }), 
                                c.end());
        std::make_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), 
                        underlying_queue::comp);
    }

};

int main()
{
    my_special_queue q;

    // standard priority_queue methods
    q.push(1);
    q.push(2);
    q.push(9);
    q.push(6);
    q.push(4);
    q.push(7);

    if (not q.empty()) {
        q.top();
        q.pop();
    }

    // apply our custom functions    
    q.clear();
    q.remove_all_odd_numbers();
}
```

Comment: This workaround method is great. I'm marking it as the solution because it's a viable, working alternative to what I wanted to do.

Comment: It's not really a workaround. It's intended design. If the standard library gave public access to the container it would be easy for a user to destroy the integrity of the heap by accident.

Comment: @Tyson no, that's my point. It is there by design. To allow people who know what they are doing access to the container, while denying it to casual users of the class.

Comment: @Richard...misunderstood what you were saying and removed my other comment. If this is intended design then you're correct, this is not a workaround.

Comment: @Tyson glad to have helped. I came across this problem myself a few years ago when I wanted to conditionally remove some items from a priority queue. I was stumped for half a day until I re-read the docs. And I wanted at all costs to avoid writing my on lacklustre priority queue implementation.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way of doing that. The reason being is that if you had access to the underlying container, you could access it and modify it like it wasn't a priority queue, which would be very confusing and against the wanted use case of `std::priority_queue`, which is to provide a queue.

This is from the Standards point of view, maybe your implementation has an extension that allows that access, but that would be very surprising, and I know no implementation that does this. You should consult the appropriate documentation to be sure.

Having said that, you can always provide a wrapper around `std::priority_queue`, which stores the container. But I would not recommend it, (as said above) you would be able to change it without the queue semantics.

Comment: Not true. there is a way. see below.

Comment: @RichardHodges I'm not saying that there is no way, I'm saying that there is no way to do it with just a `std::priority_queue` (i.e. without deriving, ...)